# How to capture the output of a PL SQL function in a powershell variable?

Tags: oracle, powershell, plsql, sqlplus

I am able to connecting to remote oracle database using powershell and sqlplus. Also I am able to capture the output of the command/query executed in the database into a powershell variable.
PFB example.

```
$username ="hr"
$password ="hr"
$tnsalias ="orcl"
$outputfilepath="C:\Users\Desktop"

 $sqlquery=@"
 set serveroutput off
 set feedback off
 set heading off
 set echo off
 select sysdate from dual;
"@
```

Running the above query in oracle database as below

```
 $xval=$sqlquery | sqlplus -silent $username/$password@$tnsalias
 echo $xval
```

The output will be

```
23-APR-18
```

The problem is when I am running a PL SQL function as below.

```
    $sqlquery=@"
     set serveroutput off
     set feedback off
     set heading off
     set echo off
     declare
     x varchar2:=null;     
     exec x:=MYTEST_FUN('a','b');
    "@
```

There is no value captured in the `$xval` variable and also the function is not running.

How to execute the function such that the return value of the function is captured in a powershell variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make it `set serveroutput on` and use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` within `BEGIN..END`

Another option is to use the sqlplus' `PRINT` command.

```
set serveroutput off
set feedback off
set heading off
set echo off
variable x VARCHAR2  --declare bind variable x
exec  :x := MYTEST_FUN('a','b'); --a colon before x needed.
PRINT x;
```

Comment: By printing the bind variable value, I am able to capture it in a powershell variable.

Comment: @rainu : Just a thing I forgot to mention. You should also prefer declaring `VARCHAR2` with a proper size to suit your output  say `VARCHAR2 (10)`

Comment: Yup I had to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```
$sqlQuery = @"
    set serveroutput off
    set feedback off
    set heading off
    set echo off
    variable x NUMBER;
        select count(*) into :x from TABLE;
    PRINT x;
    exit
"@
($sqlQuery | sqlplus -S user/pass | Write-Output | Out-String).Trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Late entry, most concisely:

```
$dateVar = ("set heading off
            select sysdate from dual;" | sqlplus -s $yourConnectionString | Out-String).Trim()
```